# Grabbing only the YAML text from a file in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, yaml

Suppose I have a file that has random text mixed with yaml text. The yaml text is always between a `---` and a `...`.

**Goal:** My goal is to take a string (taken from such a file):

```
---
some: "yaml"
some: "more yaml"
...

Some random text that's not yaml.

---
more: "yaml"
...
```

And output a string that contains **only** the yaml parts (including the `---` and `...` delimiters):

```
---
some: "yaml"
some: "more yaml"
...    
---
more: "yaml"
...
```

How does one do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily done with String.prototype.match + Array.prototype.join:

```
function extractYaml(string) {
    return string.match(/(---(.|\n)*?\.\.\.\n)/g).join('');
}
```